# How to get the count of hourly inserts on a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, amazon-aurora, postgresql-11

I need a setup where rows older than 60 days get removed from the table in PostgreSQL.

I Have created a function and a trigger:

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM table
    WHERE updateDate < NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days';
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

But I believe if the insert frequency is high, this will have to scan the entire table quite often, which will cause high DB load.
I could run this function through a `cron` job or Lambda function every hour/day. I need to know the insert every hour on that table to take that decision.

Is there a query or job that I can setup which will collect the details?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question - are you asking about how to set up a cron job?

Comment: Apologies for that @NevilleKuyt, Need a way to know the number of transactions(Inserts mostly) happened on a table every hour.

Comment: That is funny. your comment and the question title seem completely unrelated to the question. What do you want: count inserts or delete rows?

Answer (score 2):

Just to count the number of records per hour, you could run this query:

```
SELECT  CAST(updateDate AS date) AS day
    ,   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM updateDate) AS hour
    ,   COUNT(*)
FROM _your_table
WHERE   updateDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY
    1,2
ORDER BY
    1,2;
```

We do about 40 million INSERT's a day on a single table, that is partitioned by month. And after 3 months we just drop the partition. That is way faster than a DELETE.